# Unexpected token Syntax Error with the three dots while installing vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am setting up the plugin file of vuetify based on this reference:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({ ... });
```

Getting this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/plugins/vuetify.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:/codes/hkiod-mpm/client/src/plugins/vuetify.js: Unexpected token (6:33)

  4 | Vue.use(Vuetify);
  5 | 
> 6 | export default new Vuetify({ ... });
    |                                  ^
  7 |
```

I am not sure what this ... means?  Is this a new javascript syntax?  How can I get this fix?  Thanks.

Comment: The `...` is not meant to be taken literally in this case. It's a placeholder for _"here is where your Vuetify options go"_

Comment: I'm still trying to find some actual API documentation for the `Vuetify` class and so far, nothing so I totally understand your confusion

Comment: @Phil If you continue reading the same document, there is once place it mention how to pass iconfont as Vuetify param. By default, we can keep it as empty object. `{}`.

Comment: @niyasc thanks, but that's hardly comprehensive documentation

Comment: @Jason there seems to be _some_ documentation in the form of examples under the [**Customization** section of the guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/breakpoints). I'd start there